# error originates in the macro $crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query which comes from the expansion of the macro sqlx::query_as

Tags: postgresql, rust-tokio, rust-sqlx

My database and model have all the relevant fields. I want to send query to database, but I faced this error.:

```
error: error occurred while decoding column 0: expected value at line 13 column 5
   --> src/handler.rs:98:16
    |
98  |       let user = sqlx::queryas!(
    |  __^
99  | |         User,
100 | |         "SELECT * FROM users WHERE pan = $1",
101 | |         body.pan
102 | |     )
    | |__^
    |
    = note: this error originates in the macro $crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query which comes from the expansion of the macro sqlx::query_as (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I am using sqlx with Axum and postgres.

**Code**

```
let user = sqlx::query_as!(
        User,
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE pan = $1",
        body.pan
    )
    .fetch_optional(&data.db)
    .await
```

```
[dependencies]
argon2 = "0.5.0"
axum = "0.6.18"
axum-extra = { version = "0.7.4", features = ["cookie"] }
chrono = { version = "0.4.26", features = ["serde"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
sqlx = { version = "0.7.0", features = ["runtime-async-std-native-tls", "postgres", "chrono", "uuid"] }
time = "0.3.22"
tokio = { version = "1.29.1", features = ["full"] }
uuid = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
```

Comment: The proposed fix was added to the main branch: https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/pull/2670 but it hasn't been released yet.

Answer (score 1):

i also got this unhelpful error when i updated to the new version (0.7.x) SQLx.

The errors became helpful again when i downgraded to version 0.6.3.

I haven't done any work trying to figure out what changed between those two versions yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading your SQLx version in Cargo.toml, I encountered the same issue with SQLx 0.7 and it went away after downgrading to version 0.6.3